# Доп. условие на js

Tags: javascript, url, html, условия

День добрый! Подскажите, есть код

```js
if (location.search.startsWith('ссылка на страницу')) {
 document.getElementById('id_div_name').style.display = 'none'
} else {
 document.getElementById('id_div_name').style.display = 'block'
}
```

И вылетает ошибка на станицах, где нет "id_div_name" .Как это исправить?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>       at eval (eval at

Comment: Собственно выполнил код здесь - эту ошибку и видно

Comment: Ответы, которые вам предложили, вы их в консоли браузера запускаете? Если так, то обновите сначала страницу, где открыта консоль. Ошибки у вас очень уж странные

Comment: @Anamnian - Спасибо большое за ответы! Разобрался! Перепроверил подключения =)

Comment: @ThisMan - Спасибо большое за ответы! Разобрался! Перепроверил подключения =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if (location.search.startsWith('ссылка на страницу')) {
  setDisplay('none');
} else {
  setDisplay('block');
}

function setDisplay(attrName) {
  if (document.getElementById('id_div_name')) {
    document.getElementById('id_div_name').style = 'display: ' + attrName;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="id_div_name">Элемент</div>
```

Comment: Теперь вылетает ошибка "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'element' has already been declared at"

Comment: @Kron, не объявляй несколько раз `element` :)

Comment: Та я этот код занес в файл js* и подключил в движок, который генерирует страницы... Видимо из-за этого. А более универсального способа нет? :)

Comment: @Kron изменил ответ.

Comment: @Anamnian, добавил, теперь пишет эту хитрость - Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'element_id_div_name' has already been declared

Comment: @Anamnian может надо через else if() ?

Comment: @Kron Обновил ответ, теперь не используется идентификатор вообще.

Comment: @Anamnian, конечно странно, но выдает - Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'display' has already been declared
    at

Comment: @Kron Действительно, моя ошибка что не проверил. Теперь корректно ставится свойство.

Comment: @Anamnian теперь 2е появилось - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" и "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'display' has already been declared"

Comment: @Kron проблем не в коде ответа, а в том, как именно вы вставляете его к себе в скрипт

Answer (score 0):

```js
const element = document.getElementById('id_div_name'); // закешируем переменную

if(element) {
  // прям оч коротко
  element.style.display = location.search.startsWith('ссылка на страницу') ?
    'none':
    'block';
}
```

```css
#id_div_name {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='id_div_name'></div>
```

`getElementById` вернет `null`, если такого элемент нет на странице, поэтому простая проверка `if(element)` подойдет

Еще один вариант проверки

```
if(element !== null) // тоже пойдет
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку  - VM2120 main.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined  at VM2120 main.js:11 
(anonymous) @ VM2120 main.js:11 (Какой-то странный файл)
и - Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'element' has already been declared

Comment: @Kron Причем тут `jquery` и мой код? Как вы его запустили? для начала запустите его в моем ответе, ошибку не выдает никакую

Comment: @Kron для начала используйте мой код без ваших модификаций, убедитесь, что он работает, и только потом изменяйте, так легче будет отловить баг